# Unable to initialize Hybris 2205

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to initialize local Hybris 2205.3 version and getting following error -

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP27] [HacInitUpdateFacade] Failed to initialize
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalSchema' is not recognized.
```

Using Oracle JDK 17.0.4.1. Initialization triggered from HAC.

I've tried adding following property to tomcat.generaloptions also which didn't help -
"`-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all`"

Any pointers to fix this? Or need more information?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that one of the custom jar is older version and conflicting with oob. In one of our project we faced a similar issue and found that xerces.jar version in custom code was of lower version.

Both the jars I.e  in oob and custom there was xmlconstant class but lower version jar used in custom code didn't have accessExternalSchema as class variable and was being picked up by system on startup because of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JDK not supported anymore, you need to try with SapMachine 17.0.

Whole system requirements by version is [here](https://gunce.mkysoft.com/hybris-requirements/).

Comment: Thank you @mkysoft for your response.
We tried with SapMachine and still faced same result. Also, I didn't face this error when using Hybris 2105 earlier with Oracle JDK 11.
Do you think there could be other possibility?
XMLSchemaValidator class definition is changed in 2205 where we can find the xml path getting set.

Comment: Maybe you problem related with patch level. Jackson library was updated because of security issue and it was brake xml/wsdl processing. Then SAP shared another patch for it. Check here: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/eed845124da0491e875df8139c4e6e8c/f9b65161e1e645249542e59f42f64a7b.html

Comment: Thanks for trying. I had gone through the fixes list earlier and didn't find anything related. Vanilla 2205 initialization is working but with custom code it isn't. So I'm narrowing it down to my custom extensions and I need to find it.

Comment: Patch 6 released, another xml library updates.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the issue with Oracle JDK 17 only. We faced the same issue while upgrade from 2105 to 2211. This is due to jar dependency. We tried with the above given solution but it didn't work for us. We researched more and found the issue with dependency with xerces which caused conflict. We also found there is "xerces-2.12-orbeon' xerces-2.12-orbeon in OOTB. We did two things to resolve the issue

1. we updated classpath with xerces-2.12-orbeon( OOTB jar) in out custom code
2. We need to modify few code base as we were using xerces for Base64 encrytion and decryption for SSO

Please let me know if you have any questions, I will try my best to respond in time.

Regards,

Abhijit Das

Please find the link here:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/13781195/hybris-2211-upgradation-error.html?childToView=13818282